# How Can I Set Points In Firebase Database When An User Logs In or Sign Up?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set points when an User Signs Up but I dont know how can I do that because all things I search go to nowhere.

I have tried to search Google and Firebase Documentation but I didn´t find anything!

**Index.html**

This is my code to make the user login or signup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>


  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
             https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 
      authDomain: 
      databaseURL: 
      projectId: 
      storageBucket: 
      messagingSenderId: 
      appId: 
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/4.0.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/4.0.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // FirebaseUI config.
    var uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: 'index.html',
      signInOptions: [
        // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        //firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ],
      // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
      // function.
      // Terms of service url/callback.
      tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
      // Privacy policy url/callback.
      privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
        window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
      }
    };

    // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
             Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
  <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

This is my code that I am trying to use to make the save data work!

```
var db = firebase.firestore();


db.collection("users").set({
    points: 0,
    CompletedLevels: 0
  })
  .then(function (docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  });


async function savePoints() {
  let docRef = await db.collection("users").add({
    points: 0,
  })
}
async function saveCompletedLevels() {
  let docRef = await db.collection("users").add({
    CompletedLevels: 0
  })
}
```

**login.html**

This is my code that gets the API of firestore!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-database.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 
      authDomain: 
      databaseURL: 
      projectId: 
      storageBucket: 
      messagingSenderId: 
      appId: 
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>


<head> <button type="button" onclick="SavePoints()">Click Me!</button></head>

</html>
```

Comment: Not clearly the answer, but this code has the same error as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58790139/3399890).   Can you be more specific about what you are looking for here?

Comment: I literaly just want to set points to a player when he logs in my log in system!