# db.collection(...).set is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make when someone logs in my site update or create statistics.

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 
            authDomain: 
            databaseURL: 
            projectId: 
            storageBucket: 
            messagingSenderId: 
            appId: 
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

        var db = firebase.firestore();

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                db.collection("users").set({
                    points: 0,
                    CurrentLevel: 0
                })
            }
        });
        console.log(user.points);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It should be working but when I try to run it, it says in the console db.collection(...).set is not a function

What Can I Do?

Answer (score 6):

db.collection("users") returns an object of [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html). CollectionReference has no function 'set', Hence the error.
Perhaps you are looking for the function 'add' which adds documents.

Replace

```
                db.collection("users").set({
                    points: 0,
                    CurrentLevel: 0
                })
```

with

```
                db.collection("users").add({
                    points: 0,
                    CurrentLevel: 0
                })
```

And I think that should solve your problem

Comment: You can also do `.collection(...).doc().set(...)` (which makes it easier to factor out commonality between create and update modes.